# Change contentBackgroundColor of List with itemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, list, flex4, flash-builder, itemrenderer

Hey there-  I'm attempting to change the contentBackgroundColor of a List component depending on the content found within the dataprovider.  For instance:

```
<s:ItemRenderer name="ir"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    autoDrawBackground="true"
    contentBackgroundColor="{(data.location == 'home')?0x000000:0x666666}">
```

Unfortunately this seems to be ignored as the list just shows the default white background.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would override the set data setter method and set the style there since you are guaranteed to catch every change to the data:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
    super.data = value;
    this.setStyle("contentBackgroundColor", value.location == "home" ? 0x000000 : 0x666666);
}
```

Comment: Good call, but still ignored.  If I trace(value.location) within the itemrenderer set data method, it traces more times then I have location elements in my xml.  Twice as many + 1 in fact.  Very odd behavior...

Comment: Hmmm, what happens if you set autoDrawBackground to false?  Also, another approach would be to set it to false and add a Rect to the background of your item renderer and set the fill color however you like.

Comment: With autoDrawBackground = false, keeps the background white, but item highlighting is now off.  I will try the Rect solution, saw that on an adobe help page too.

Comment: Adding <s:Rect> 
  <s:fill> 
   <s:SolidColor color="0x000000"/> 
  </s:fill> 
 </s:Rect> doesn't work.

Comment: You need to give it dimensions.  Either width/heigh 100% or left, right, top, bottom = 0.

Comment: Also, you need to set the color on the Rect, not the contentBackgroundColor (in case that wasn't clear).

Answer (score 1):

ItemRenderer extends from Group which doesn't respect contentBackgroundColor, but rather passes it through to its elements as an inheriting style.

So contentBackgroundColor does work, but not as you are expecting, if you were to put a component that does respect contentBackgroundColor into your renderer then it will get that color, for example:

```
<s:List>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:String>0</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer contentBackgroundColor="red">
                <s:VGroup paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10">
                    <s:Label text="ItemRenderer {data}" />
                    <s:ComboBox />
                </s:VGroup>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

As pointed out earlier you will probably be best off overriding the data setter and changing the color of a background Rect from there, for example:

```
<s:List>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:String>0</fx:String>
            <fx:String>1</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                            super.data = value;
                            if (data == null)
                                return;

                            if (data == 1){
                                c.color = 0xEEEEEE;
                            } else {
                                c.color = 0x666666;   
                            }
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
                <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:SolidColor id="c" />
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>
                <s:Label text="ItemRenderer {data}" />
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Comment: What if your itemRenderer is external and you have multiple labels within one Horizontal Layout. For instance: `<s:layout>
  <s:HorizontalLayout gap="0" variableColumnWidth="true" paddingBottom="14" paddingLeft="0" paddingTop="14" horizontalAlign="center" />
 </s:layout>
 <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
  <s:fill>
   <s:SolidColor id="c" />
  </s:fill>
 </s:Rect>
 
 <s:Label id="locationLbl" width="60" />
 <s:Label id="opponentLbl" width="90" />
 <s:Label id="timeLbl" width="60"/>
 <s:Label id="dateLbl" width="60" />`

Comment: This is hard to explain.  If I apply the code above to my external itemRenderer, it renders a colored box just before the start of the first label.  If the criteria in the if conditional are true, it renders that colored box a certain color.  However, as I scroll my List, it acts strangely and renders other boxes that color as well, in a random kind of way.  I hope that makes sense.